# Controllling an industrial robotic arm

Tags: robotic-arm, precise-positioning

How can you control a servo driver (delta, ...) with an industrial PC?

To control position and velocity of a servo you need PWM signal to the servo drive (amplifier), but how do we create the signal and using which component?  Would a 555 timer be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

**Controlling a Servo from a PC is more than just generating a PWM signal**

The indication that you want to control the PWM signal for the Servo from a PC implies that your want to close the servo control loop yourself.  I have done that before and it is VERY HARD (it took us several thousand man hours to create).  Much of the code has to reside in the Windows Driver/HAL layer to get the response time you need.  PC's (or at least Windows PC's) are not designed for the realtime response that is needed to close a servo control loop (typically 500uS loop time with better than 5uS determinism).

If you want to control an industrial servo from a PC, I recommend you either use an external diver/controller Ex: [SureServo](http://www.sureservo.com/drives.htm); or, if you are going to use a desktop PC, you could use one of the PCI controllers Ex: [OmsMotion](http://www.omsmotion.com/).

A lot of the decision depends on what exactly you want to do (high power complex coordinated motion profiles, simple on/off high power motor, or low power control).

Comment: Thanks for your replay it was very helpfull,but how do i give the velocity /angle/force information to the drive,i know it has the i/0 inputs ,but what software do they need or what interface,i already know about controlling them using plc,but i need another way,so i can make a program in c++ in order to put equations and control the servo

Comment: Sounds like another good question.  When you post the question, it would be helpful to add information about the specific motor you want to control as well as the computer and OS you want to control it from.